# How to improve PNG data decoding time?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, libpng

Decoding a png image of size 1080x1920 takes over 30ms and I'm looking to do it faster.

In Android [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) has a method where you can pass the [sample size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to be returned. This causes the returned decoded image to be smaller then the actual source. This in turn makes the decoding process a lot faster with the outcome of a lower quality image.

I want to do something similar in c++ using some png decoding library such as libpng but for some reason I can't find any details about decoding at a lower quality.

Any pointers or ideas to improve decoding time would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To ask for a lower resolution image in the decoding would have zero influence in CPU work: a PNG stream is basically a compressed ZLIB stream which must be fully decompressed, and inside that there is a PNG-specific unfiltering to be done, which, again, requires all the neighbouring pixels. Of course, subsampling could lead to less memory usage, (which in itself can result in less decoding time), for this you'd need to decode the PNG progressively (so that the subsampling is done line by line); you can do that with (my) Java library [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/); it's optimized for that usage pattern, and some people have used succesfully in  Android.

If you want to do it in C, with libpng, the idea would be the same. Decode the image progresively, line by line, and do the subsampling yourself.

Bear in mind that this usage pattern would break with interlaced PNG (in that case, you'd want to decode one of the subimages), but, anyway, to store a 1080x1920 image as interlaced PNG would be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I did figure it used zlib to compress the image but wasn't 100% sure. To improve multiple image decoding I created decoder thread workers. I send request for 2-3 images to be loaded and it ends up being slightly faster since I'm assuming the OS is making the different threads run on different CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

Android is open source; you could look at the source: [the Java interface](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/5e3a10ede11dda4ec94cf3d20e3bcbc6e0fb0144/graphics/java/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java) and [the C++ backend](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/5e3a10ede11dda4ec94cf3d20e3bcbc6e0fb0144/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp#L208) - from there, it calls to the [SKIA library](https://code.google.com/p/skia/).

[This class](https://code.google.com/p/skia/source/browse/trunk/src/images/SkScaledBitmapSampler.cpp#331) appears to be where the sampling is done; it is called from [here](https://code.google.com/p/skia/source/browse/trunk/src/images/SkImageDecoder_libpng.cpp#300).

Comment: Thx! I was able to see what they are doing... It seems like skia is simply reading the entire image and then down sampling. :/ It is using libpng and my guess is that Android uses a really optimized build. https://code.google.com/p/skia/source/browse/trunk/src/images/SkImageDecoder_libpng.cpp